# How can I increase UITableVIew's performance?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a multithreaded app that has a table view. It does data gathering in the background on a different thread. The problem is, when the user scrolls the table, the data gathering slows by a whopping 75%. And there's a lot of data to gather, so I want to have table scrolling reduce data-gathering speed by no more than 15% if that's possible.

Is there perhaps a way to make the TableView only redraw when the user takes their finger off the screen? Don't worry about user experience, let me worry about that. If you have any ideas at all that could speed it up, I'd like to hear them.

Comment: Are you meaning that scrolling the table will slow down your connection? Have you given a look with the Time Profiler tool in Instruments? Is redrawing of the table the real culprit of the slowdown?

Comment: But why dont you use NSNotification for reload cell data when the thread gets completed.. and data is ready to load in table view... go through this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial   Using NSNotification i think you will not need reduse speed of scrolling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your bottleneck is the "data-gathering" in the background, so you might consider attacking that. You could try pre-fetching a lot of the data and caching it in memory before displaying your table view controller.

You could also try just redrawing part of the cell (for example, only the text and not any images) if it is particularly complicated. For the expensive operations you could do perform selector with a delay of 0, and that will throw it to the next iteration of the run loop (good strategy all around).

Best thing you could do thought is run Instruments with the Time Profiler and attack what's sucking up the most CPU.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is  returning nil from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` when the user is dragging. You can check whether the user is doing so by calling [`self.tableView.dragging`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/dragging) or `self.tableView.tracking`, and `self.viewTable.decelerating` (this to identify when the drag or track is about to end).

Comment: That throws an exception but thanks for the suggestion. I save a little bit of speed by returning an empty cell unless self.viewTable.decelerating, but not enough. Even if I just return empty cells no matter what, it's not fast enough.